# Tridiagonal Matrix Algorithm with Numba nopython mode

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, numpy, numba

I am trying to write a [TDMA algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix_algorithm#Method) with numba in nopython mode. Here is my code:

```py
@jit(nopython=True)
def TDMA(a,b,c,d):
  n = len(d)
  x = np.zeros(n)
  w = np.zeros(n)
  #   ac, bc, cc, dc = map(np.copy, (a, b, c, d)) # copy arrays
  ac = np.copy(a)
  bc = np.copy(b)
  cc = np.copy(c)
  dc = np.copy(d)
  for i in range(1,n):
    w[i] = ac[i-1]/bc[i-1]
    bc[i] = bc[i] - w[i]*cc[i-1]
    dc[i] = dc[i] - w[i]*dc[i-1]

  x[n-1] = dc[n-1]/bc[n-1]
  for k in range(n-2,-1,-1):
    x[k] = (dc[k]-cc[k]*x[k+1])/bc[k]
  return np.array(x)
```

Then test this solver:

```py
A = np.array([[5, 2, 0, 0],[1, 5, 2, 0],[0, 1, 5, 2],[0, 0, 1, 5]],float)
B = np.array([[15],[2],[7],[20]],float)
a = A.diagonal(-1)
b = A.diagonal()
c = A.diagonal(1)
x1 = np.linalg.solve(A,B)
x2 = TDMA(a,b,c,B)
print('by default solver, x1 = ',x1)
print('by TDMA, x2 = ',x2)
```

However, my TDMA function fails with a `TypingError`:

```
TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Cannot resolve setitem: array(float64, 1d, C)[int64] = array(float64, 1d, C)

File "<ipython-input-20-e25cda7246bd>", line 16:
def TDMA(a,b,c,d):
    <source elided>

  x[n-1] = dc[n-1]/bc[n-1]
  ^
```

It works properly with `@jit` decorator, but fails with in `nopython` mode. How should I modify this TDMA function to make it compatible with `nopyhon`?

The line I commented:

```py
ac, bc, cc, dc = map(np.copy, (a, b, c, d)) # copy arrays
```

Is not compatible to `nopython` either. Is it possible to use the `map` function in `nopython` mode?

I understand that my TDMA may be still slow. So is there a fastest code using python 3 language to implement Tridiagonal Matrix Algorithm?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have 2D arrays but index and assign them like they are 1D arrays. So you could just `ravel()` them before passing them to the numba function. I'm not sure if that's actually correct - but for the purpose of this answer I assume that it is.

Also you don't need to copy `a` and `c` because you don't modify them and you actually only need to copy the first element of `b` and `d`.

So a working function might look like this:

```
import numba as nb
import numpy as np

@nb.njit
def TDMA(a,b,c,d):
    n = len(d)
    x = np.zeros(n)
    bc = np.zeros(len(b))
    bc[0] = b[0]
    dc = np.zeros(len(d))
    dc[0] = d[0]
    
    for i in range(1, n):
        w = a[i - 1] / bc[i - 1]
        bc[i] = b[i] - w * c[i - 1]
        dc[i] = d[i] - w * dc[i - 1]

    x[n - 1] = dc[n - 1] / bc[n - 1]
    for k in range(n - 2, -1, -1):
        x[k] = (dc[k] - c[k] * x[k + 1]) / bc[k]
    return x
```

And you call it like this:

```
TDMA(a.ravel(), b.ravel(), c.ravel(), B.ravel())
```

Because I used `ravel()` the result doesn't have the same shape as the `np.linalg.solve`:

```
by default solver, x1 =  [[ 3.05427975]
 [-0.13569937]
 [-0.18789144]
 [ 4.03757829]]
by TDMA, x2 =  [ 3.05427975 -0.13569937 -0.18789144  4.03757829]
```

However I really wouldn't re-implement NumPy functions except when you can utilize some structure in your data that the NumPy function doesn't know. NumPy is a high-performance library that already uses really fine-tuned implementations so a casual re-implementation might only be faster for extremely small data-sets or in case you can exploit some facts about your data (that allow an extremely more performant algorithm).

I have to admit that I don't know "Tridiagonal Matrix Algorithm" but I know that some [BLAS libraries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Linear_Algebra_Subprograms) (generally incredible fast math libraries) implement it. And NumPy uses BLAS.

However SciPy provides some (very fast) special linear algebra solvers for special matrix types:

> [Basics](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.2.1/reference/linalg.html#basics)
>
> - `inv(a[, overwrite_a, check_finite])` Compute the inverse of a matrix.
> - `solve(a, b[, sym_pos, lower, overwrite_a, …])` Solves the linear equation set a * x = b for the unknown x for square a matrix.
> - `solve_banded(l_and_u, ab, b[, overwrite_ab, …])` Solve the equation a x = b for x, assuming a is banded matrix.
> - `solveh_banded(ab, b[, overwrite_ab, …])` Solve equation a x = b.
> - `solve_circulant(c, b[, singular, tol, …])` Solve C x = b for x, where C is a circulant matrix.
> - `solve_triangular(a, b[, trans, lower, …])` Solve the equation a x = b for x, assuming a is a triangular matrix.
> - `solve_toeplitz(c_or_cr, b[, check_finite])` Solve a Toeplitz system using Levinson Recursion
>
> [...]

Regarding your question with `map`: The current official [list of supported built-in functions](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/pysupported.html#built-in-functions) does not include `map`. So you cannot use `map` in Numbas nopython mode.